# How to remove Malware from Magento?

Tags: magento, malware

I am using **Magento 1.7.0.2 community edition**.
7 days ago I faced an issue with Google search.
Whenever my site is searched on Google and any user click on result link than my site was redirecting them to some advertisement site.
I analyzed the code and came to conclusion that dre is a malware code in each php files which redirect users who are coming through search engine.

I cleaned up my website and installed new code and changed all my FTP passwords.
Again after 4-5 days i am facing same issue.
I don't know why this is happening.

Could anyone please help me here?

Comment: This doesn't really sound on-topic on Stack Overflow. Have you checked Magento's community support resources? If this is a Magento vulnerability, you're likely to find better help there.

Comment: Yup, I have asked this question their also, but have not found any response there. That's why I decided to post it in front of bigger community.

Answer (score 0):

Did you contact your hosting company to make sure that they are using the latest OS software and firewall?

You could also think about change your hosting company. Does any other domain at your hosting having this issue?

Assuming that you are hosting your site remotely and not using any vpn/firewall, you should NOT be using FTP. See [FTP security](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaj4/rzaj4rzaj45zpftpsolutions.htm)